# Uncontrolled Format String Vulnerability in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vulnerability, format-string, data-validation

I have been working on input validation vulnerabilities and very new to Uncontrolled Format String Vulnerabilities, as I learned so far its usually exploited through `printf` functions with "`%`".

I also saw that JavaScript (Node.JS) supports format strings by using `sprintf` functions.

Is it possible to perform Format String attacks in JavaScript, because in [CWE](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/134.html) it is only mentioned that it is rarely seen in Perl, oftenly in C and C++. If it is possible are there any examples or any source that I can find.

I tried myself with a simple example but it end up with an error `expecting number but found string "Bob"`

```
var val = "Bob"
console.log(sprintf('The %x ran around the tree', val));
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right, any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, these are not possible in Node.js as `sprintf` is a basic string formatting utility. This is now built into the language as [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_format_format).

As per the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_format_format), this function only supports basic formatting such as `%s`, `%d` and `%j`. There is no way of retrieving a pointer value using `%p`, hex formatting it using `%x` or outputting the number of characters using `%n`, which is where the vulnerability lies in C. [C documentation on the formatting options here](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/format.html).

C is a native language, so it is possible to cause a buffer overflow using string format. However, Node.js is a managed language and it is not possible to directly control registers, therefore you won't get the same type of vulnerabilities here.

[See here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_String) for some format string exploit examples.